# I use kingsoft spreadsheets. Want a cell to change colour if the cell is false

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, formula, kingsoft

I have this formula:
`=Y606=SUM(I606:X606)`

Can anyone please advise me how to make the cell colour change colour if false?

Answer (score 2):

As follows from the header of your question, you are using **Kingsoft Spreadsheets**.

So, you need to use [Conditional Formatting](http://help.kingsoftstore.com/spreadsheets/home-tab/styles/conditional-formatting).

---

If you have this formula i.e. in cell `Z606` than

**1.** select `Z606` cell

**2.** select *"Format" -> "Conditional Formatting"*

[image]

**3.** select *"Cell value is"* and *"equal to"* in the left

**4.** enter `FALSE` in the right textbox

**5.** choose format style you want to apply

**6.** press *"ok"*  and that's all:)

[image]

**Result:**

[image]